# awk to process multiple sorting at one go

Tags: awk

I'm just trying to remove `"[]"` , `"out:"` & `nameserver` from the output, as i'm First getting the lines which are haing `nameserver` in the file.

Then again i'm using awk again to process and remove the mentioned  values, i'm sure there will be smart way to do that without calling awk twice.

```
$ awk '/nameserver/'  dns_file
[keanx61.ddl.COM]            out:  nameserver  192.22.48.33
[keanx61.ddl.COM]            out:  nameserver  192.22.48.23
[keanx61.ddl.COM]            out:  nameserver  172.144.71.11

$ awk '!/^$/ { gsub( /[][]|out:|nameserver/ , "" ); print $0 }' dns_file
keanx61.ddl.COM  192.22.48.33
keanx61.ddl.COM  192.22.48.23
keanx61.ddl.COM  172.144.71.11
```

Comment: your command can be merged into one like `awk '/nameserver/ && !/^$/{ gsub( /[][]|out:|nameserver/ , "" ); print $0 }'`

Comment: $ awk '/nameserver/ && !/^$/ { gsub( /[][]|out:|nameserver/ , "" ); print $0 }' dns_file

Comment: @PS., you are correct , that i got working but looking if there is any such short smarter way :)

Comment: can also use `awk -F'[][]| +' '/nameserver/{print $2,$NF}'`...(not sure which all awk versions supports this) @PS. if `nameserver` is found in line, it can't be empty anyway

Comment: @Sundeep, nice trick indeed, can you explain that `+' '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'[][]| +' '/nameserver/ { print $2, $NF }'
```

The `-F` option sets the input field separator, which in this case is a regular expression (in single quotes to keep the shell from messing with it): `'[][]'` matches either `[` or `]`, while `' +'` (that's a space followed by a plus sign; the space is important here!) matches one or more spaces. Putting them together with the alternation ("or") operator `|` to get `'[][]| +'` yields a regular expression which matches either a single square bracket or any number of spaces.

Every time the parser finds a match for the field separator, it starts a new field, so your name server lines are split into fields like this:

```
 [keanx61.ddl.COM]            out:  nameserver  192.22.48.33
^field 1 (empty)
  ^field 2 
                  ^field 3 (empty)
                              ^field 4
                                     ^field 5   ^field 6
```

So in that specific line, `$1` is `""`, `$2` is `"keanx61.ddl.COM"`, `$3` is `""`, `$4` is `"out:"`, `$5` is `"nameserver"`, and `$6` is `"192.22.48.33"`.

We only care about the hostname (`$2`) and the IP address; since the IP address is the very last field, we don't actually have to count past 2. We can just ask for "the last field", `$NF`.

Comment: Mark Reed, Thanks for Nice explanation.

Comment: Mark Reed, where from that `""` is coming ?

Comment: The `""` aren't literal, @KarnKumar; I was just using them to delimit the field values so I could easily represent the empty string as `""`.